# PowerShell 6.2.4 : Get-Clipboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, clipboard

I would expect `Get-Clipboard` to work from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7)

I am on PowerShell 6.2.4 and MacOs Catalina?

```
Get-Clipboard : The term 'Get-Clipboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At /Users/.../debug.ps1:41 char:1
+ Get-Clipboard
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Clipboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell [Core] v6.x has *no* clipboard cmdlets - you'll have to wait for v7.0** for them to return (the available preview releases have them).

<sup>The [documentation URL in your link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7) ends in `?view=powershell-7`, indicating a v7.x topic; **there's a dropdown list labeled "Version" to select a different PowerShell version**; if you had selected `6`, you would have been told that no such page exists for v6.x</sup>

In the meantime, you have two options:

- Use platform-specific tools such as `pbpaste` / `pbcopy` (macOS) and `xclip` (Linux distros with X11-based desktop), and `clip.exe` / the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly on Windows.
- Use the [`ClipboardText`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=clipboardtext) third-party module (authored by me; [repo](https://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardTexthttps://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardText)), which wraps the above tools for you (text support only, via commands `Set-ClipboardText` and `Get-ClipboardText`).

  - The module also works with *Windows PowerShell versions v2-v4*, which similarly lack clipboard utilities.